# Self Referencing in Entity Framework 6 Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have these class in my code :

```
public class Parent
{
    [Key]
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
    public string ParentName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Child> Childs { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    [Key]
    public int ChildID { get; set; }
    public string ChildName { get; set; }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ParentID")]
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

`Parent` have one-to-many relationship with `Child` and `Child` have `Parent` property. Is this going to cause me trouble in the future? Because I just got `Self referencing loop detected` exception when trying to convert this class into `JObject` with Newtonsoft. Am I suppose to remove `Parent` property from `Child` so it doesn't cause self referencing?

Comment: Please have a look at my answer on **[“Self Referencing Loop Detected” exception with JSON.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40472419/self-referencing-loop-detected-exception-with-json-net/51235783#51235783)** page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you indeed have a circular reference when you go to serialize either one of these classes. The parent has a list of children which in turn links back to the parent.

Decorate `Child.Parent` with a [`JsonIgnoreAttribute`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonIgnoreAttribute.htm) and it will stop trying to serialize this property. It's definitely useful as a navigation property but I can't think of a single practical case you'd want the entire Parent object serialized as a member of a Child. (The parent's id might be useful to keep though.)

Comment: Alright, but let's ignore about newtonsoft and talk about my EF `dbSet` design, is this a common design or I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: It's fine. You have a reverse navigation property and it operates exactly like you think it will. This is very common, although I sometimes omit it at first if I don't think I will traverse the hierarchy backwards.

Answer (score 0):

There is two way to handle this error.
First, you can ignore navigation property (virtual ICollection). Because. this is for navigation and serializing this effects

> Self referencing loop detected exception

This occurs either Newtonsoft or XmlSerializer.

Second, you can use `POCO` class without proxy to serialize.